# syntax error near unexpected token '(' in C 7

Tags: c, syntax

I am having problem with the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int tall = 175;
    int weight = 68;

    printf("I am %d slim.\n", tall);
    printf("I am %d kilogram.\n", weight);

    return 0;
}
```

i have created these code following a course but i have an issue (The Compiler said that )

```
./file.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./file.c: line 3: `int main()'
```

for more information I am using GCC in linux destro ..
and i am using terminal To run ...
there's No IDE

Comment: And the program you show is the actual program you try to compile? There's nothing else you don't show us? No special and invisible Unicode characters?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. Suggested signature of `main`: `int main(void)`.

Comment: [can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/823Xs0)

Comment: Yes i am just a new in programing yes this's the full code that i am trying to compile there's no invisible unicode characters

Comment: i have tried int main (void) too and it does not work at all

Comment: And what happen if You make Your `main` look like this: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`? I don't see any parameters in `main`, but it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @hiicham07; I didn't say it will work after that. It was a suggestion. Posted code seems [fine](https://ideone.com/MMKW2c). Read the [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515253/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-in-c-7#comment54813006_33515253).

Comment: Can you compile another program ? Like a helloword.c programme ?

Comment: yes i have tried this too it shows ./dz.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./dz.c: line 3: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])'

Comment: i want to tell you that it seccess and works when i put this code #include `<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age = 10;
    int height = 72;

    printf("I am %d years old.\n", age);
    printf("I am %d inches tall.\n", height);

    return 0;
}`

Comment: Nice Great help brother BobRun it fixes my problem now it's working perfectly ? but The question why when i rename it to this specific name (helloword) it works perfectly ? what's the reason? 
`./helloword
I am 175 slim.
I am 68 kilogram.`

Comment: i want to say Thanks to all about Your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are not compiling your program, but that you are trying to execute it without compiling. The errors that you see is `/bin/bash` that tries to interpret this as shell code.

Comment: no i compile it by this command gcc -Wall -o dz.c and i have change name to electron.c and it didn't work but when i changed it to helloword.c it works with the same commands first gcc -Wall -o helloword.c after that chmod +x helloword.c after that ./helloword to run and it works ? i have tried that to the other names it didn't work at all

Comment: Your line `gcc -Wall -o dz.c` is wrong. Don't add executable rights to the source file.  With your command line you  *write* to `dz.c`, instead of reading and compiling it. Use `gcc -Wall -o dz dz.c` and then execute `dz`.

Comment: Thank you Bro i understand now where's my problems thank you very much